# AWS Unload statement error

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to run the following query to do an unload from Redshift into S3, and am getting an unhelpful error.  We have tried escaping all characters that might cause problems, and are passing in parameters (the wrapper program is in Python):

```
unload ('select
            user_id
            ,course_id
            ,request_month
            ,user_agent_type
            ,count(session_id)
         from
                (select distinct
                    user_id
                    ,context_id as course_id
                    ,date_trunc(\'month\', request_timestamp) request_month
                    ,session_id
                    ,case
                    when user_agent like \'%CanvasAPI%\' then \'api\'
                    when user_agent like \'%candroid%\' then \'mobile_app_android\'
                    when user_agent like \'%iCanvas%\' then \'mobile_app_ios\'
                    when user_agent like \'%CanvasKit%\' then \'mobile_app_ios\'
                    when user_agent like \'%Windows NT%\' then \'desktop\'
                    when user_agent like \'%MacBook%\' then \'desktop\'
                    when user_agent like \'%iPhone%\' then \'mobile\'
                    when user_agent like \'%iPod Touch%\' then \'mobile\'
                    when user_agent like \'%iPad%\' then \'mobile\'
                    when user_agent like \'%iOS%\' then \'mobile\'
                    when user_agent like \'%CrOS%\' then \'desktop\'
                    when user_agent like \'%Android%\' then \'mobile\'
                    when user_agent like \'%Linux%\' then \'desktop\'
                    when user_agent like \'%Mac OS%\' then \'desktop\'
                    when user_agent like \'%Macintosh%\' then \'desktop\'
                    else \'other_unknown\'
                    end as user_agent_type
                from {}
                where context_type = \'Course\')
                group by
                    user_id
                    ,course_id
                    ,request_month
                    ,user_agent_type')
to {}
credentials 'aws_access_key_id={};aws_secret_access_key={}'
manifest
gzip
delimiter '|'
```

The error is the following:

```
2016-03-04 14:28:12,208 [CRITICAL] - Error occurred during transaction: syntax error at or near "month"
LINE 12:     ,date_trunc('month', request_timestamp) request_month
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the word "as" before request_month